# Hive regex serde match a filename

Tags: regex, hive

I have a hive table of 5 string fields

```
permission owner filename blockSize blockCount
```

The hive table uses regex serde to match the groups

```
hive > alter table my_table SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+));
```

But this regex doesn't work with filename with spaces. How should I change my regex to match the 3rd group to any file names? I found it hard to achieve because fields are separated by spaces but file name can also have multiple spaces.

Comment: Seems each fields are separated by \t, so instead of using (\\S+) I guess I need something like "match anything unless I seen a tab" in my 3rd group.

Comment: Or maybe just one backslash?  (\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)